# Function isn't adding the 2 matrix

Tags: functions, matrix

Having an issue where my function rotMatfromVec won't add the 2 Matrices at the end. It takes in 2 inputs, R and theta, where R is a unit vector.

```
rotMatfromVec[R_, Theta_] :=
  Module[{i, j, k},
    i = {1, 0, 0};
   j = {0, 1, 0};
   k = {0, 0, 1};
   
   iR = Dot[i, R] R;
   jR = Dot[j, R] R;
   kR = Dot[k, R] R;
   mR = N[MatrixForm[{iR, jR, kR}]];
   
   iP = i - iR;
   jP = j - jR;
   kP = k - kR;
   mP = N[MatrixForm[{iP, jP, kP}]];
   
   iC = Cross[R, iP];
   jC = Cross[R, jP];
   kC = Cross[R, kP];
   mC = N[MatrixForm[{iC, jC, kC}]];
   
   mCP = Cos[Theta] mP + Sin[Theta] mC;
   M = MatrixForm[mR + mCP];
   Return[M];
   ];
Print["M = ", rotMatfromVec[i, Pi/2]];
```

This keeps evaluating to this answer and not performing the addition

```
{{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,-1,0}}+{{1,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use `MatrixForm`. It is only for display.

Comment: Get rid of all the calls to `MatrixForm`

Comment: Thank you Roman and QuantumDot, I'll try and remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rotMatfromVec[R_, Theta_] :=
With[{i = {1, 0, 0}, j = {0, 1, 0}, k = {0, 0, 1}},
   iR = Dot[i, R] R;
   jR = Dot[j, R] R;
   kR = Dot[k, R] R;
   mR = N[{iR, jR, kR}];
   iP = i - iR;
   jP = j - jR;
   kP = k - kR;
   mP = N[{iP, jP, kP}];
   iC = Cross[R, iP];
   jC = Cross[R, jP];
   kC = Cross[R, kP];
   mC = N[{iC, jC, kC}];
   mCP = Cos[Theta] mP + Sin[Theta] mC;
   M = mR + mCP;
   Return[M];];
rotMatfromVec[{1, 0, 0}, Pi/2] // MatrixForm
```